# Use of the visual cortex in mathematical thinking?

Tags: vision, mathematical-ability, visualization

In modern computers (and programming) one makes alienated use of the high powers of graphical processing units (GPU) for non-graphics-related tasks, enhancing drastically the power of the general purpose central processing units (CPU).

I wonder if any attempts have been made to explain high-performance in abstract (but geometry related) mathematics (by people like [William Thurston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Thurston), [Sergej Perelman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Perelman), [Alexander Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck), to name just a few in no specific order) by an extraordinally strong and specific use of the visual cortex (and not only of the associative, speech-related and other parts of the cortex that are usually involved in mathematical thinking). At least the role of "inner geometric visualization" is often emphasized (without being completely understood, as I guess - not even what this means).

For example, in his [laudation](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1983.1/Main/icm1983.1.0011.0014.ocr.pdf) for the Fields medal winner of 1982, William Thurston, C.T.C. Wall says:

> Thurston has fantastic geometric insight and vision; his ideas have
> completely revolutionized the study of topology in 2 and 3 dimensions,
> and brought about a new and fruitful interplay between analysis,
> topology and geometry.

So my question is for any study that might have been performed in this direction - or for any theoretical approach that has been made.

---

*[One guiding idea might be the following: Consider the concept of a 5-dimensional hypercube. Just **trying** hard and often to mentally visualize such a cube (which would correspond to some specific neuronal activities in the visual cortex) would "improve" (somehow) mathematical thinking about higher dimensions in other parts of the cortex - even if it's not successfull, i.e. no clear mental picture arises. (Of course, trying to do so would be "informed" by those other parts, so dependency is bidirectional.)]*

> *Possible follow-up question (not to be answered here!):*
>
> *Which characteristics of either the visual cortex or the other parts
> of the cortex being concerned with mathematical thinking make it
> possible to use the visual cortex in this way (whatever "this way"
> is)? Or could just everyone use it this way?*

Comment: Related: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/why-cant-we-use-100-of-the-brain-in-a-certain-moment

Comment: Thanks. But this is only rather loosely related, isn't it?